# AWS Python script (Rekognition) working when called from command line, but not automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-rekognition

i am working on a script which uploads pictures to S3 and then adds that picture to a rekognition collection. When i run this script from the command line everything works perfectly - no issues. However, when the system executes it automatically (the script runs whenever a new file is added to the specified upload folder) the rekognition portion of the code does not run. Everything up through os.remove works fine automatically, but i can't get the images added to the collection. After days of messing with the code i am looking for some help - please let me know if i am missing something here.

After messing around with the script a bit and debugging it is client=boto3.client('rekognition') which for some reason does not allow the script to run. Any thoughts on why that would be?

````
import boto3
import os

#Get file name of newly uploaded picture
path = "/var/www/html/upload/webcam-capture/"
files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:
 #Split up file name for proper processing
 components = name.split('-')
 schoolName = components[0]
 imageType = components[1]
 idNumber = components[2]

 # Upload files to  bucket with Python SDK
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 s3.meta.client.upload_file(path + name, schoolName + '-' + imageType + '-' + 'media.XXX.school', idNumber)

 # Delete file from webcam-capture temp folder
 os.remove (path+name)

 #Add Face to Facial Recognition Collection
 collection_id = schoolName + '-' + imageType
 bucket= collection_id + '-media.XXX.school'
 client=boto3.client('rekognition')
 response=client.index_faces(CollectionId=collection_id,Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':idNumber}},MaxFaces=1,QualityFilter="AUTO",DetectionAttributes=['ALL'])```
````

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @JulienSimon should have closed this out -I ended up moving on and doing this through lambda which is working. It should have worked in my original script but I couldn’t spend any more time on it.